# is data being encrypted when SSL certificate is expired?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, https

When you visit a website and it shows (not secure) with a red lock icon, does that mean the data is not being encrypted?

Normally when an SSL certificate is valid two things will happen:

- your computer will verify that the website you access is the real one (verification)
- the incoming and outgoing data will be encrypted (encryption)

Are they working together or there are some cases when verification fails but encryption still works?

is there a way to check if the encryption is working? and block the access if the encryption is not working?

Comment: HTTPS means either it's encrypted or no data is sent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data is still encrypted. The red lock icon is only a warning that the certificate has expired.

Comment: Not according to my experiments. When the red lock appeared on Chrome the TLS handshake failed and no data was sent at all.